# Analytics and A/B testing subscription on iOS

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, subscription

We are trying to find a way to run analytics and A/B test on a per-user basis on our iOS app that uses subscriptions through iTunes. As far as I've found, there doesn't seem to be a way to match subscription revenue data to a user of our app, which makes performance analytics and A/B testing very difficult.

Is there something I'm missing? How are subscription apps out on the app store running their analytics?

Comment: There's no official analytics from Apple, but you can create your own attribution/testing framework based on events with Mixpanel or similar tools.

Comment: @Oddie thanks for your reply. How would that work? Since subscription renewal and cancellation can be controlled from outside the app. How can I capture these events with those tools you mentioned?

Comment: This is hardly to place to give you a step-by-step guide on how to do that, but Google is your friend (ios subscription attribution): https://help.tune.com/marketing-console/validating-auto-renewable-subscriptions-for-in-app-purchases/ or https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/213826123-Tracking-Automatic-Subscription-Revenue-in-AppsFlyer-iOS-